# How to run a command from a windows service?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I wrote a C# service program to execute a windows command. It is not executing the command but the service is working properly. anyone, please help me to fix this

**code**

```
public partial class ScheduledService : ServiceBase
{
    Boolean armed = false;
    //Initialize the timer
    //This method is used to raise event during start of service
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    public ScheduledService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }        

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        //add this line to text file during start of service
        TraceService("start service");

        //handle Elapsed event
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);

        //This statement is used to set interval to 1 minute (= 60,000 milliseconds)

        timer.Interval = 10000;
    }


    //This method is used to stop the service
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        timer.Enabled = false;
        TraceService("stopping service");
    }

    private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        ExecuteCommandSync("echo.|clip");
        TraceService("Another entry at "+DateTime.Now);
        System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.Clear();                
    }

    private void TraceService(string content)
    {
        //set up a filestream
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"d:\ScheduledService.txt",FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

        //set up a streamwriter for adding text
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);

        //find the end of the underlying filestream
        sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);

        //add the text
        sw.WriteLine(content);
        //add the text to the underlying filestream

        sw.Flush();

        //close the writer
        sw.Close();
    }

    public void ExecuteCommandSync(object command)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            proc.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception objException)
        {
            // Log the exception
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `ExecuteCommandSync` with the command you want work as expected in a simple console application? Have you tried to debug it? The code looks fine so far...

Comment: everything is working except the command part, and returns no error !

Comment: So what do you expect to happen? If I execute `echo.|clip` in a cmd, nothing happens. So your code seems to work as expected.

Comment: I wish to clear my clipboard. that is not happening when i run this code.

Comment: Ok, so it could help if you post the relevant part of the logfile you created (`scheduledService.txt`) _after_ you added a call to the log method in your `catch` block. And a guess: Is it possible that `echo.|clip` is working per-user? (so if you service is running as LocalSystem it would not clear _your_ clipboard?)

Comment: not any exceptions throwing, I printed the exception message to scheduledService.txt

Comment: I am not sure  about `echo.|clip` per-user

Comment: I guess the command to clear the clipboard is echo off | clip, I have just tested your code with echo off | clip and it works, it cleared my clipboard.

Comment: I checked the command in cmd, its working.

Comment: @Дмитрий Иванович Менделеев, So you mean to say that it is working (clearing clipboard) from your command prompt but not from the above code

Comment: I verified it, it works if you execute the code in a normal console app, but it has no effect when executed as a service, no matter what user account the service is running in or if it's interactive or not....interesting problem, I hope someone can tell you the reason..

Answer (score 0):

You are calling OnElapsedTime after every 10 second, but not doing anything in this function except LogTracing. I guess you wanted to call ExecuteCommandSync from OnElapsedTime to run command.